# How to import data from one sheet to another based on 2 cell criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I am trying to manage my sheet by using filter formula using 2 criteria is this possible or do I do I need to use another formula.

what I am using is

=Filter('Form Responses 1'!B2:U,'Form Responses 1'!B2:B="Original","Follow Up")

It does not work
it does work if I omit the **,"Follow Up"** but it does not give me all the data I need.

I want to show all the Originals and Follow ups on one sheet.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

If I have "interpreted"* your request correctly, try this calculation:

```
=Filter('Form Responses 1'!B2:U,('Form Responses 1'!B2:B="Original")+('Form Responses 1'!B2:B="Follow Up"))
```

*that is, you want to get all the cells with the wording "Original" OR "Follow Up"